# how to use Style.Triggers for Canvas in WPF

Tags: wpf

I want to make a simple effect for a canvas by this code, but it doesn't work.

```
<Canvas.Style>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Canvas.IsMouseOver"  Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Background" Value="LightSkyBlue">
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Canvas.Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `<Style>` element is missing a `TargetType`. Because controls can be made up of multiple controls you can use `TargetType` to target different control types and doing so will also give you contextual intellisense for the children Elements.

```
<Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="215,128,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100">
    <Canvas.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Canvas">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"  Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Background" Value="LightSkyBlue">
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Canvas.Style>
</Canvas>
```

I feel like CSS really did a great job at making styling easy so it's a bummer that WPF has to be so esoteric.